# What are all these Harry Potter objects?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-items, object-identification

The first three or four were especially confusing to me, I'm not sure what they are. What are all these Harry Potter objects?

[image]

(it's apparently from [this article](http://mashable.com/2013/11/02/harry-potter-minimalist-posters/), though I couldn't view the page).

Comment: It's quite annoying that this fan-image appears to have been cropped to remove the artist's signature.

Comment: @Valorum hmm, well it wasn't me. :)

Comment: I'm blaming you :-)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in the version with Jessica Martinez' signature.

Comment: It's annoying me slightly that the accepted answer (based purely on the OPs guess) has 75 upvotes and has been accepted and my answer (based on the pictures that the post is based on and the word of the original artist) has 7 upvotes and isn't accepted.

Comment: @Valorum I'm sorry my post is so annoying for you. Please don't be upset with me. I accepted Rogue Jedi's answer because he edited to include links and visual comparisons from the movie items, which is helpful for someone who couldn't tell what they were just by looking at the drawings. I was very tempted to accept yours though, I really like your answer. Here, have a bounty :)

Comment: Your bounty is much appreciated. I was only a *little* annoyed though. Not upset :-)))

Comment: I was genuinely joking and i'm certainly not annoyed at you *personally*. People always take what I say the wrong way

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From left to right:

1. [The Philosopher's (Sorcerer's) Stone](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher's_Stone)

[image: The Philosopher's (Sorcerer's) Stone]

2. [Tom Riddle's Diary](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/T._M._Riddle's_Diary) (with inkwell and quill)

[image: Tom Riddle's Diary]

3. [A Time-Turner](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Time-Turner)

[image: A Time-Turner]

4. [The Goblet of Fire](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Goblet_of_Fire)

[image: The Goblet of Fire]

5. [A Prophecy Record](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Prophecy_Record)

[image: A Prophecy Record]

6. [A pensieve](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Pensieve)

[image: A pensieve]

7. [The sign of the Deathly Hallows](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sign_of_the_Deathly_Hallows)

[image: The sign of the Deathly Hallows]

Each object seems to represent a book/movie, going in chronological order from *The Philosopher's Stone* to *The Deathly Hallows*.

Comment: I was thinking the quill could be another magical quill, such as the Black Quill, one that took dictation, or one that wrote or corrected answers by magic, but those would be out of order.

Comment: I got all of them except the prophecy record. Nice!

Comment: I assumed the sixth item is the stone basin of potion in the island in the cave, the basin where the Dark Lord hid his locket Horcrux.  This one appears on the back cover of the British edition of *Prince*.  The book says (chapter 26) the basin is “rather like a Pensieve”.  However, the book also definitely says the basin emits a *greenish* light.

Answer (score 21):

The creator of the gifs that your image is based on ([Jessica Martinez](https://jecamartinez.com/)) has stated on her website that the pictures are **inspired and derived from artifacts from the seven Harry Potter books**.

> A set of animated minimalist fan art GIFs inspired by my favorite book
>   series.

It may amuse you to learn that she also included a *hidden lightning bolt* in each picture to commemorate Harry's iconic scar.

---

**The Sorcerer's Stone** (from "*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*")
[image]

**Tom Riddle's Diary as well as the inkwell and quill used by Harry** (from "*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*")
[image]

**Hermione's Time-Turner** (from "*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*")
[image]

**The Goblet of Fire** (from "*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*")
[image]

**Harry's prophecy** (from "*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*")
[image]

**Dumbledore's Pensieve** (from "*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*")
[image]

**The symbol of the Deathly Hallows** (from "*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows"*)
[image]

Comment: Can someone tell me where the lightning bolt is on the CoS gif? Is it the feather??

Comment: @Alistair86 - It's the slight cut in the top right of the feather.

Answer (score 10):

First one is Philosopher's Stone, Then Tom Riddle's Diary, Then the Time Turner, Then the Goblet of Fire, Then the Sphere that told the fortune about Harry Potter Or the Remeberball, Then the Pensive, and the last is the Deathly Hollows Items, the Elder Wand the Invisible Cloak and the Resurrection Stone.

Comment: any idea what the greenish circle above the diary and the feather next to it are? (Also I think you're right about the larger ball being the prophecy from book five.) :)

Comment: @RedCaio both answers are correct, however, roguejedi is more specific, also the dark circle thing above the diary is an inkwell and the feather is a quill pen

Comment: @RedCaio It looks to me like they're a quill and inkpot (seen from above), which wizards would use to write (and which presumably Ginny used to write in the diary).

Comment: The quill could have been a QuickQuote quill or the punishment quill, but they would be out of place chronologically, would not represent a book since all books are already represented, and would not explain the inkpot above the diary.